# how to increase and decrease the image alpha value with animation in ios sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios

In this code i am using animation.But at a time i need to change the image alpha value also.

```
-(void)animation
{
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(imgView.frame.origin.x, imgView.frame.origin.y);
    imgView.layer.position = point;
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
    anim.fromValue  = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
    anim.toValue    = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(point.x + 50, point.y)];
    anim.duration   = 10.0f;
    anim.repeatCount =1;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    [imgView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
    imgView.layer.position = point;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `opacity` key of `CABasicAnimation` for doing this:

```
CABasicAnimation *alphaAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
alphaAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
alphaAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
[imgView.layer addAnimation:alphaAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];
```

**Edit:**

For animating through specified values you can use `CAKeyframeAnimation`:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.duration = 10.0f;
    animation.repeatCount = 1;
    animation.values  =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0,
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],nil];
    animation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0], nil];
    [imgView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];
```

Comment: @user2545298: With pleasure :)

Comment: hi..Also another requirement is when image is changing it's x position alpha value should be decrease that means image will be seen lighter.After that it came to next position image should be brighter.               Thank's in advance if u have any solution share to me.

Comment: @user2545298: I modified my answer, please check

Comment: I don't know if this has been changed since this answer is posted. But keyTimes is a relative normalized value array. Each value in the array is a floating point number in the range [0,1]. So the three keyTimes above should be [0, .5, 1].

Comment: As a side note,  I had animation.isAdditive = YES,  and then opacity will just cummulate and be max.  So, set it to isAdditive = NO to act correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to decrease the alpha as the same time/rate the x position of your view is moving, just put the position setting code together with the alpha setting code in the same block of animation, like below:

```
CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(500, imgView.center.y); //change for any final point you want
CGFloat finalAlpha = 0.0; //change the final alpha as you want
UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ //change the duration as you want
   imgView.alpha = finalAlpha; 
   imgView.center = finalPoint;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//your code of changing x position will be here
```

now implement my code which is written below.

```
 UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
imgView.alpha = 0.5;//must be in between 0 to 1
 }];
```

now when your imageview move to next position as you are saying, write below code

//your code for imageview for next position..
now implement below code...

```
 UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
imgView.alpha = 1.0;//must be in between 0 to 1
 }];
```

let me know it is working or not!!!! Hope it helps...

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: hi..my requirement is when image is changing it's x position alpha value should be decrease that means image will be seen lighter.After that it came to next position image should be brighter.               Thank's in advance if u have any solution share to me.

Answer (score 0):

This "fades to invisible" `self.view` in 500ms.

Anything you do prior to invoking it will be set "immediately", everything you set within the `animation' block (like setting new frame coordinates) will be interpolated over the specified duration.

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50
                              delay:0.0
                            options:(   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                     |  UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                     |  UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut)

                         animations:^ {
                             self.view.alpha = 0.0f ;
                         }

                         completion: ^(BOOL){
                             [self.view removeFromSuperview] ;
                             self.view = nil ;
                         }
         ] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `CABasicAnimation` object (a different one because you will animate a different KeyPath, namely `alpha`, for this) and use `NSNumbers` for `fromValue` and `toValue`.

Another (and easiest) way is to use the `UIView` helper methods dedicated to animation ( `animateWithDuration:…` and all), especially if you have to animate multiple properties at the same time (you may animate both the `frame` and the `alpha` with the same animation block if it fits your needs and simplify your code).

You can also mix `CABasicAnimation` for the frame and `[UIView animateWithDuration:…]` for the alpha, whatever combination you need depending on if your animations are complex and need to be customized (custom timing function, non-linear animation, …) or not.